# Progress reporting with Apache Tika?

Tags: java, pdf, zip, filesize, apache-tika

I am using Apache Tika with Java to extract text from PDF and Zip files. Now while processing large files, I want to add progress reporting to my application. For that I need estimated extraction size to calculate the percentage done (by matching it with the number of bytes written to output).

I've searched a lot and cannot find anything related to this anywhere.

Does apache tika provide any kind of progress reporting?
Is there any workaround for this?

Edit: 
I'm using the java libraries of apache tika `tika-parsers`, `tika-server` from the group `org.apache.tika`. And directly invoking them through Java with the following code.

```
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ParseContext context = getParseContext(extractionPolicy, parser);
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
parser.parse(inputStream, handler, metadata, context);
return metadata;
```

Comment: Are you handling embedded resources in the files? And if so, how? And how are you calling Apache Tika in the first place - Server, App, Java code, Python etc?

Comment: No I'm not explicitly handling any embedded resources. And I'm using the tika libraries `tika-server` and `tika-parsers` in the group `org.apache.tika`.

Comment: The Tika Server is a standalone runnable REST server, you either want to run that outside your main JVM, or use Tika Core + Parsers from within your program! Post the code you're actually using

Comment: I posted the code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going about it the wrong way. For progress reporting instead of estimating the output bytes and extraction size, I counted the read bytes on the input stream.

Wrap the input string in `CountingInputStream` class provided by either AWS SDK or Apache Tika, and match the read bytes with total content bytes to get the percentage.

```
CountingInputStream inputStream;
Long totalContentLength;

private int getProgressPercentage(){
    Long processedBytes = this.inputStream.getByteCount();
    if (0 < totalContentLength && processedBytes <= totalContentLength) {
        int percent = (int) ((processedBytes * 100.0 / totalContentLength));
        LOGGER.info("Processed bytes: {}, Total bytes: {}, Progress: {}%", processedBytes, totalContentLength, percent);
        return percent;
    }
    return 0;
}
```